# Database proxy for pods in Kubernetes

Tags: database, kubernetes, proxy, aws-lambda, database-connection

If I have a large number of pods in Kubernetes which have multiple live DB connections, is there any way to manage all these connections to reduce the number of open connections? For example, using a database proxy. I'm aware AWS does this for lambda function containers (RDS proxy).

Is there something similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

Not related to Kubernetes per se. It really depends on what database or service you are running and/or what language your application is written in. Examples:

- Postgresql. You can use something like [PgBouncer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer).
- Mysql w/Java. [Connection Pooling with Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html).
- Mysql w/Python. [Connection Pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html).
- GCP Cloud SQL. [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy).
- Etc.